# frequency of the variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

prg below tries to count the instances of variables.

```
%macro freq(dsn=,variable=,freq=,label);

proc freq data = &dsn;
tables &variable;
run;

%mend;
%freq(dsn=fff,variable=ggg);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'assign a label and display it' ? Also, this is not a code-on-request service - please make an effort to do this yourself and ask a specific question if you get stuck at a particular step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to do this by adding a format and print procedure. I have tested this and I believe it achieves what you are looking to accomplish.

```
%macro freq(indsn=,variable=,freq=,label);

/* Create a new format or label when a value falls between
   0 and the user defined frequency. */
proc format;
    value fmt    0-&freq. = "&label.";
run;

/* Run the frequency procedure and suppress the output
   to a temporary data set. */
proc freq data = &indsn;
tables &variable / noprint out=temp;
run;

/* Print the temporary data set and format the Count
   variable (which was created in the freq procedure)
   to the format, fmt, that we created. Finally, print only
   records with a frequency less than the user defined
   frequency. */
proc print data=temp noobs;
    format count fmt.;
    where count le &freq.;
run;

%mend;
```

With your recent edit you will be able to accomplish this with a data step and an if statement.

```
%macro freq(indsn=,variable=,freq=,label);

/* Run the frequency procedure and suppress the output
   to a temporary data set. */
proc freq data = &indsn;
tables &variable / noprint out=temp;
run;

/* Assign variable a new name if its frequency equals the
   user defined frequency and only keep records with a count
   less than or equal to the frequency. */
data temp;
    set temp;
if count le &freq.;
if count = &freq. then &variable. = &label.;
run;

/* Print only the &variable variable. */
proc print data=temp noobs;
var &variable.;
run;

%mend;
```

Comment: As this stands this is not a very good answer.  While providing code to answer questions is generally a good thing, you should answer the question in more than just code, by describing how your answer solves the problem and how it works.

Comment: @Joe i need to code to see how many times a vriable value is repeated it the repeated value is equal to the freq= 'parameter ' then assign a diff label/value "XYZ" to it. so in the out put it should be the new label displayed instead of the repeated variable value.

Comment: @Joe Sorry for the vague answer, I have updated to provide a bit more clarity as to what the code is doing.

Comment: Thanks, J_Lard.  It might be better with some not-comments details (i.e., plain english explanation), but this is better for sure than just code.